# UITableView reloadData is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm creating the UITableView datasource array using this code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // IBOutlet of tableview is 'editMsgTableView'
    editMsgTableView.dataSource=nil; 
    editMsgTableView.delegate=nil;

    menuMessageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    editMainMenuMsgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    menuMessageArray = [DBManager fetchmenu:0 noOfRows:32];

    for(int i=0; i< [menuMessageArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *menuMsgListDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        menuMsgListDic = [menuMessageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [editMainMenuMsgArray addObject:menuMsgListDic];  
    }

    editMsgTableView.dataSource=self;
    editMsgTableView.delegate=self;
    [editMsgTableView reloadData];
}
```

But it works for the first time. But whenever I do some tableView editing stuff or comes from another view controller,after that if `viewWillAppear`is called then `reloadData` is not working. I also tried:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [editMsgTableView reloadData];
});
```

but not working. Please help me out.

Comment: maybe your reload is called but noting is changed. Do the delegate methods of tableview get called?

Comment: is your data source array get updated data? check that too.

Comment: First of all, do you really want to populate the contents of your table everytime your view will appear? Have you debugged if numberOfSectionsInTableView get called?

Comment: Why you are removing and setting `datasource` & `delegate` of `editMsgTableView ` each time in `viewWillAppear`. Instead set `delegate` and `datasource` in `viewDidLoad`. Use `dealloc` method for releasing.

Comment: @FawadMasud : Yes, everything is working fine.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Yes, I'm printing the array everytime. and after editing it is changed.

Comment: @Kampai: to make sure that tableview should generate after creating the complete array which is fetched from the database.

Comment: That does not make sense. It is an IBOutlet it won't require to be delegate each time also many people set delegate and datasource from Storyboard. So to update datasource you just need to `reloadData`.

Comment: 1. check in debug, maybe tableView is nil
2. look on frame, constraints you tableView. add background color for her

Answer (score 3):

When editing begins call `[tableView startUpading];` and when editing is done, call `[tableView stopUpdating];` then `[tableView reloadData];`.

Comment: this can easily go in comment

Comment: @tod not enough repo :)

Answer (score 0):

Try ,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [editMsgTableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you giving to that viewController the tableViewDelegates correctly? :

`@interface theNameOfTheViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` in the .h file?

i suggest not to do this:
`editMsgTableView.dataSource=nil; 
    editMsgTableView.delegate=nil;
editMsgTableView.dataSource=self;
    editMsgTableView.delegate=self;`

just this:

```
[self.editMsgTableView reloadData];
```

be sure that all the delegate methods are called when you use reloadData (put a breakpoint in every delegate method that should be used to reload the Data of the table when you make a change or the view Appears), remember that  reloadData method, calls all delegate methods (if you´re giving to the view controller correctly the delegate as I said before) of the tableViewController. If nothing of this helps you, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are navigating the view from one view to another view, then you should call `[tableView reloadData]` on `ViewDidLoad`.
This is because of the view life cycle - when you are coming back from one view and your `tableView` data source is updated, the view life cycle will be like this:

1. `viewDidLoad`
2. `tableViewDelegateMethods`
3. `viewDidAppear`

So when you update `tableView`'s data source object and call `reloadData` during `viewDidLoad` will resolve the issue.